# Given n points in the plane, such that the minimal euclidian distance is 1, show that there are at most 3n pairs of points with distance exactly 1

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, planar-graphs

Here's the problem:

> Given n points in the plane, such that the euclidian distance between each pair
>   of points is at least 1. Show that there are at most 3n pairs of
>   points with distance exactly 1.

Well, this exercises is part of an assignment about planar graphs, so my intuition is to build such graph.

Then I defined the following graph:

let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that $\{e,v\}\in E \iff distance(u,v) =1 $.

Then, using contradiction to the assumption, I managed to prove that this graph is planar.

With that, knowing that planar graphs as at most $3n-6$ edges, I concluded that in particular they have at most $3n$ edges.

Does it make any sense?

Thanks

**EDIT** this is my proof for the planarity:

Assuming the graph is non-planar. Let a,b,c,d be vertices in the graph such that $ \{a,b\},\{c,d\} \in E$   and those edges intersect each other. Let $o$ be the intersection point. Assuming WLOG that $dist(b,o)<dist(a,o)$ and $dist(c,o)<dist(o,d)$ then both $dist(c,o),dist(b,o)<\frac{1}{2}$. Let's have a look at the triangle $\Delta boc$. 
Let's use the following marks: $dist(o,b)=x$, $dist(o,c)=y$ and $dist(c,b)=z$
From the triangle inequality, we know that $|z|\leq |x|+|y|$, but $x,y<0.5$ Than $ z < 0.5+0.5=1$ In contradiction that each 2 points has distance of at least 1.

Comment: How did you manage to prove that the graph is planer?

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan just edited

Comment: I think this looks good. I personally would avoid the confusion between *planar graph* and *planar embedding of a graph*. Even if your particular embedding into the plane might have intersecting edges, the graph might still be planar, you just found the wrong embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly correct.